# Sublime terminal shortcut "subl ." is not opening the directory I am in

Tags: sublimetext3

I just installed Sublime Text on my new Macbook. The `subl` executable is at:

```
/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
```

The first line of my `.zshrc` is:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When I echo my PATH, I get:

```
echo $PATH
  
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

When I type `subl .` into my terminal, my Sublime application opens but not to the directory that I am in i.e. the files of the present directory are not visible in the side bar.

For example, when I enter the following in my terminal:

```
➜ pwd 
/Users/samhenderson/Documents/apps

➜ ls  
index.js

➜ subl .
Timeout waiting for detached instance to start: No such file or directory
```

I get the following (note index.js is not present in the side bar):

[image]

Comment: The reason for that would be the error message you're getting; if it can't talk to the running instance, it can't communicate to it that it should open the folder. Do you see any errors in the Sublime console? When you installed Sublime, did you unarchive the zip file using the command line `zip` tool or did you do it via Finder?

Comment: I moved the Sublime application from Downloads into Applications using Finder. There isn't an error message in the Sublime console. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

kill all sublime instances ( check the Activity Monitor )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).